# Maven - Could not reserve enough space for object heap error

Tags: maven, jvm

I am Maven to build my Java project. After several successful build, I am now getting the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

In my maven.sh file that my build is using, I have added the following as the first line

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m
```

I am still getting the error.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: at what stage in the maven build is this failing? Is it during the tests run for example? could you provide more of the maven output?

Comment: `[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ my-configuration ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\target\surefire-reports
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.`

Comment: It fails regardless if I run my tests or not. It fails very early in the build. I am using a Windows machine and the Linux emulator Cygwin to run my maven build. The build also fails when I try it in Windows. It previously worked in Cygwin but not now.

Comment: certainly seems strange. Take a look at the following blog: http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/mvn-clean-install-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap/ also try the various suggestions in the comments as well. Maybe one of those will help you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution was to set the forkMode of maven-surefire-plugin to 'never'. It seems that when tests are run, maven sure fire spawns a new JVM. Setting it to never fixed the issue.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <configuration>
        **<forkMode>never</forkMode>**
        <argLine>-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m</argLine>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <user.name>${user.name}</user.name>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and I figured Maven was not using the right jvm. You can check this with

```
mvn -version
```

In my case, the jvm specified in my `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` was incorrect: I was using an x86 jdk 6 instead of an x64 jdk 7. Fixing this solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue when I was trying to build the Cloudera Navigator SDK examples.  I am using a 32-bit JVM and the compile seemed to go OK but the test afterwards failed with this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

I tried setting MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m but this had no effect- it failed with the same message.  Even the value of 2097152KB in the error message was still the same (strange!).

I finally figured out that the heap size value had been hard-coded for the test in the pom.xml file!  It had

```
<argLine>-Xmx2048m ...
</argline>
```

I edited pom.xml and changed that to -Xmx1024m and then maven was able to build and test everything with no problems.

So the lesson from this is that if you are building something given to you by someone else (such as Cloudera) and you get an error like this, check pom.xml carefully to see if the setting is hard-coded in there.

FYI- I think that using a 64-bit JVM might have also possibly resolved this, but I can't switch to 64-bit.  We have some other stuff that we need to get this to work with that says that it only works with a 32-bit JVM (I can't really explain in any more detail than that here).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to reserve more space than you have, with your settings:
`MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m`

Try to set it lower, since Maven starts only if it can reserve the whole space.
This problem occurred to me and I could solve it like described.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set variable:
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m

Answer (score 2):

Changing  to MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx512m  helped me on a Windows 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try Java 64 bits and configure your java_home to this Java 64.
obs.: javac -version and mvn -version needs return this Java 64.

Answer (score 0):

As Didier L above said

This was exactly what problem I was having, we were running the x86 JVM instead of the 64 bit...

It fixed my issue when I changed to the 64bit JVM.

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA IntelliJ IDE there is a setting on `Maven -> Runner` to use a specific JVM.  The default for me was to use the JRE and not the JDK set on JAVA_HOME. Make sure to check that setting. Once i switched to use JAVA_HOME everything ran fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its works for me-

maven version -3.2.5
java version -jdk1.7.0_10

-Xmx600m -XX:PermSize=256m